# MongoDB - filter documents to one per day

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a collection of events.  In my app these events are added to the events collection many times a day.  Each event has an eventName attribute that is a string.  Each event also has a data object that contains a few data points.  Some of those data points change throughout the day, but one stays the same.  I want the data that stays the same all day.
I would like to write a mongo query that get events of the eventName turnOn but I only want one for each day.

My collection:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5789449365109ca974906921"),
    "eventDate" : ISODate("2016-07-15T20:16:18.508Z"),
    "eventName": "turnOff",
    "data" : {
        "sameAllDay" : 2000,
        "variesAllDay1" : 1234,
        "variesAllDay2" : 2345,
    }
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5789449365109ca974906921"),
    "eventDate" : ISODate("2016-07-15T20:16:13.592Z"),
    "eventName": "turnOn",
    "data" : {
        "sameAllDay" : 2000,
        "variesAllDay1" : 1235,
        "variesAllDay2" : 2346,
    }
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5789449365109ca974906921"),
    "eventDate" : ISODate("2016-07-15T20:16:03.507Z"),
    "eventName": "turnOff",
    "data" : {
        "sameAllDay" : 2000,
        "variesAllDay1" : 1236,
        "variesAllDay2" : 2347,
    }
}

/* 4 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5789449365109ca974906921"),
    "eventDate" : ISODate("2016-07-15T20:15:58.592Z"),
    "eventName": "turnOn",
    "data" : {
        "sameAllDay" : 2000,
        "variesAllDay1" : 1237,
        "variesAllDay2" : 2348,
    }
}

/* 5 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5789449365109ca974906921"),
    "eventDate" : ISODate("2016-07-16T20:15:48.507Z"),
    "eventName": "turnOn",
    "data" : {
        "sameAllDay" : 3000,
        "variesAllDay1" : 1238,
        "variesAllDay2" : 2349,
    }
}

/* 6 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5789449365109ca974906921"),
    "eventDate" : ISODate("2016-07-16T20:16:18.508Z"),
    "eventName": "turnOn",
    "data" : {
        "sameAllDay" : 3000,
        "variesAllDay1" : 1209,
        "variesAllDay2" : 9876,
    }
}
```

What I want:

```
/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5789449365109ca974906921"),
    "eventDate" : ISODate("2016-07-15T20:16:13.592Z"),
    "eventName": "turnOn",
    "data" : {
        "sameAllDay" : 2000,
        "variesAllDay1" : 1235,
        "variesAllDay2" : 2346,
    }
}

/* 5 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5789449365109ca974906921"),
    "eventDate" : ISODate("2016-07-16T20:15:48.507Z"),
    "eventName": "turnOn",
    "data" : {
        "sameAllDay" : 3000,
        "variesAllDay1" : 1238,
        "variesAllDay2" : 2349,
    }
}
```

Here is my query so far:

```
db.getCollection('event').aggregate([
  {$match: { 'eventName': 'turnOn' }}, 
  {$sort: { 'eventDate': -1 } }
  //filter to one event per day
])
```

How can I get set of turnOn events where each event in the set has a unique day? Time of day does not matter.  Month and Year do matter.

Comment: do you want  only the last event `turnOn` per day or the first event `turnOn` per day? In your requirement, for `2016-07-15` this is the last `turnOn` of the day, and for `2016-07-16` this is the first `turnOn` of the day

Comment: I don't care if it's the first of the day or that last of the day.  They each contain a data point called "sameAllDay" which is the same for every event for a given day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do like this :

- 2 `$project` (additionnal one for concat year-month-day)
- 1 `$match`
- 1 `$group`
- 1 `$sort`

mongo query is :

```
db.event.aggregate([{
  $project: {
    _id: 1,
    eventName: 1,
    data: 1,
    day: {
      "$dayOfMonth": "$eventDate"
    },
    month: {
      "$month": "$eventDate"
    },
    year: {
      "$year": "$eventDate"
    }
  }
}, {
  $project: {
    _id: 1,
    eventName: 1,
    data: 1,
    eventDate: {
      $concat: [{
          $substr: ["$year", 0, 4]
        },
        "-", {
          $substr: ["$month", 0, 2]
        },
        "-", {
          $substr: ["$day", 0, 2]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}, {
  $match: {
    "eventName": "turnOn"
  }
}, {
  $group: {
    _id: "$eventDate",
    eventDate: {
      $first: "$eventDate"
    },
    data: {
      $first: '$data'
    }
  }
}, {
  $sort: {
    eventDate: 1
  }
}])
```

It will do the following :

- 1st `$project` : separate year/month/day from date
- 2nd `$project` : concat date
- `$match` your `eventName`
- `$group` by the created date year-month-day with only the first date & first data
- `$sort` date

Output gives you :

```
{
  "_id": "2016-7-15",
  "eventDate": "2016-7-15",
  "data": {
    "sameAllDay": 2000,
    "variesAllDay1": 1235,
    "variesAllDay2": 2346
  }
} {
  "_id": "2016-7-16",
  "eventDate": "2016-7-16",
  "data": {
    "sameAllDay": 3000,
    "variesAllDay1": 1238,
    "variesAllDay2": 2349
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  The query runs but the result is empty.  If I try the query without the $group I get a result.  What does the _id: "$eventDate" do?

Comment: It means it groups by date, precisely by the value "YYYY-MM-DD" generated previously with projection. I have exactly the same values as you have written them in your question, try to execute these in your console : https://gist.github.com/akinaru/895639fb19c133a6a47fb6b83b8a8aa1

Comment: I got it working now.  Your latest link was helpful.  Thanks so much!